# Can i have both an ArrayList and a Comparator in the constructor of a TreeSet?

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

Assume i have a class Pet with attributes name(String) and age(int) in an ArrayList and i want to sort them without using the Collections Framework so i use a TreeSet to parse the ArrayList.My Question is, is there a way to initialize a new Comparator inside the constructor of the TreeSet(alongside the ArrayList) or do i have to implement a new Comparator/Comparable in the Pet Class?

Already tried it by implemeting a Comparable in the Pet Class and it worked, but i was wondering as to whether there is a shorter way by using the TreeSet constructor.

```
ArrayList<Pet> myPets = new ArrayList<>();

// TreeSet to compare names
TreeSet<Pet> sortedPets = new TreeSet(myPets, new Comparator<Pet>() {                                         
    public int compare(Pet p1, Pet p2) {
        return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `TreeSet` constructor that takes both a `Comparator` and a `Collection`, but you can create a `TreeSet` with a `Comparator` and then populate it with `addAll`:

```
TreeSet<Pet> sortedPets = new TreeSet(new Comparator<Pet>() {                                         
    public int compare(Pet p1, Pet p2) {
        return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    }
});
sortedPets.addAll(myPets);
```

Implementing `Comparable` in the `Pet` class would make sense only if you consider ordering of `Pet`s by their names to be the natural ordering of `Pet`s.